# Javascript ajax call doesn't trigger Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I'm trying to get some text on a page to change depending on what is selected from a drop down bar, but can't get my javascript to call my Django function to determine the text so the placeholder text is never replaced.

JS:

```
function updateDateRange(){
  text = "";
  $.ajax({
    url:'/report/api_report_dates/',
    data: {'option':selection_criteria_date[0]},
    type: 'POST',
    error: function(){alert('Error!');},
    success: function(){
        text = "Date Range: " + infoDict['start_date'] + " to " + infoDict['end_date'];
    },
  });
```

urls.py:

```
(r'^report/$', 'report_view.view_report'),
(r'^report/api_report', 'report_view.api_report'),
(r'^report/api_report_dates', 'report_view.api_report_dates'),
```

report_view.api_report_dates:

```
def api_report_dates(request):
    infoDict = {}
    infoDict['start_date'] = (gets start date from request.option, else is "")
    infoDict['end_date'] = (gets end date from request.option, else is "")
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(infoDict), content_type="application/json")
```

The placeholder text appears where it should before an option is selected, and the alert 'Done!' shows up when I would expect it to.  But it never changes the text, and I've set a breakpoint at the start of report_view.api_report_dates but the debugger never hits it except at page load.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:** dhana's response helped me out, have updated code to reflect current state.  My issue now is that the ajax is going into neither 'error' or 'success' clauses.

In case versions matter, this site uses Django 1.2 and JQuery 1.4.2

Comment: You need to move all the logic in `success` callback - It is not accessible outside of it.

Comment: if this is your code verbatim, in your success function your quotes are messed up. should be `text = "Date Range:" + infoDict['start_date'] + " to " + infoDict['end_date'];`

Comment: Also you dont have a parameter on your success function, so you arent storing the response from the server.

Comment: Thanks pseudonym!  It was just the lack of success parameter.  Also the quotes were just a typo from copying.

Answer (score 0):

You should write this way,

```
function updateDateRange(){
  $.ajax({
    url:'/report/api_report_dates/',
    data: {'option':selection_criteria_date[0]},
    type: 'POST',
    error: function(){alert('Error!');},
    success: function(){
alert('Done!');

  text = "Hello!"
  if (infoDict['start_date'] != '') {
    text = "Date Range: " + infoDict['start_date'] + " to " + infoDict['end_date'];
  } 

},
  }); //returns infoDict with 'start_date' and 'end_date'
```

In urls.py file add this

```
(r'^report/api_report_dates/$', 'report_view.api_report_dates'),
```

in report_view.api_report_dates:

```
import json

def api_report_dates(request):
    infoDict = {}
    infoDict['start_date'] = "some date"
    infoDict['end_date'] = "some date"
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(infoDict))
```